# Exibição de resultados de join na view com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web

Estou aprendendo `laravel` e estou com uma dúvida relativamente simples referente a uma consulta utilizando `join` em laravel. 
Como faço para acessar o valor do campo `categoria.name` na minha `view`.
Segue a consulta e a `view` respectivamente.

**Função da Controller**

```
public function list()
{
    $products = produto::join('categoria','category_id','=','id')->select('produtos.*','categoria.name');
    return view('Product/list',compact('products'));
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('body')
@if (count($products) > 0)
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">NAME</th>
        <th scope="col">STOQUE</th>
        <th scope="col">PRICE</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($products as $p)
        <tr>        
        <td>{{$p->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->stoque}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->price}}</td>
        <td>
                <a href="/product/{{$p->id}}/edit"  class="btn btn-dark">EDIT</a>
                <a href="/product/delete/{{$p->id}}"  class="btn btn-danger">DELETE</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach 
    </tbody>
</table>
@else
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        Não existem produtos cadastrados
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
@endif
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginando o cenário que uma categoria possui vários produtos, e vários produtos podem pertencer a uma mesma categoria, temos um relacionamento n:m.

Recomendo o seguinte:

Arquivo **Produto.php**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Categoria;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Produto extends Model {
    // o código existente da sua classe aqui

    /**
     * Recupera as categorias do produto.
     * @see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships
     */
    public function categorias(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Categoria::class);
    }
}
```

Arquivo **Categoria.php**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Produto;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Categoria extends Model {
    // o código existente da sua classe aqui

    /**
     * Recupera os produtos da categoria.
     * @see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships
     */
    public function categorias(): BelongsToMany {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Produto::class);
    }
}
```

Tendo seus models definidos, no controlador vc poderia fazer assim:

Arquivo **ProdutoController.php**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Models\Produto;

class ProdutoController extends Controller {
    // seu código existente aqui

    public function listar(): View {
        // https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading
        $produtos = Produto::all()->load('categoria');
        return view('Product/list', ['products' => $produtos]);
    }
}
```

Aí na sua view vc exibe os dados da forma que achar melhor. No caso de querer exibir o nome das categorias:

```
@foreach ($products as $p)
    <tr>        
        <td>{{$p->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->stoque}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->price}}</td>
        <td>
        @forelse ($p->categorias as $c)
        {{ $c->name }} <br>
        @empty
        Nenhuma categoria relacionada a este produto.
        @endforelse
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

A leitura que fiz é que uma categoria pode ter n produtos relacionados e vice-versa, desta forma, vc pode exibir na view de listagem de produto vc pode exibir todas as categorias que um mesmo produto está relacionado. Caso as regras de negócio da aplicação que você está desenvolvendo defina que um produto pode estar relacionado a somente uma categoria, será necessário trocar os métodos de relacionamento do Eloquent, de belongsToMany para hasMany() (de Produto para Categoria - models) e belongsTo() (de Categoria para Produto - models). [Leia mais sobre](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Tenta adaptar e vê se consegue algum resultado. Importante salientar que esta é uma abordagem pouco elegante, muito direto ao ponto e engessada. Quando estiver mais familiarizado com o framework, [use suas convenções](http://www.laravelbestpractices.com/), [helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers), [paginação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination), [injeção de dependência](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers), [padrões de projeto também, recomendo o padrão de repositório](https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce) para você estruturar melhor suas classes e [evitar acoplamentos de código que vão te dar dores de cabeça em manutenções futuras](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/pat/lowcoupling.htm)!

*PS: Fiz os códigos de cabeça (adaptação do copy&paste) e não testei pq estou sem ambiente apropriado no momento. Caso apresente algum erro, coloca aí pra gente tentar achar a solução!*

Answer (score 1):

Se a tabela de produtos e a tabela de categorias tiverem um campo chamado name, você deve criar um `alias` ou apelido para um dos campos, então ficaria assim:

```
$products = produto::join('categoria','category_id','=','id')->select('produtos.*','categoria.name as nome_categoria');
```

Nesse exemplo eu dei um apelido para o campo `name` da segunda tabela, chamando o de `nome_categoria`.
Ai na `view` você pode chamar assim:

```
<td>{{$p->nome_categoria}}</td>
```

Sugiro que leia sobre o `Eloquent` e suas relações. Pois auxilia e muito nestes processos de Join e deixa o código menos complexo.
Segue os link da doc sobre o Eloquent:
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent),
[Relacionamentos no Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).